# How to use the default terminal settings when opening a .terminal file OSX

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, settings, plist

I have a need to be able to open the OS X terminal on users' computers for an application I am developing.  I want to use the default user settings for terminal but the best way I have found to launch the terminal is using a .terminal Plist file and calling the open command with that file.  Is there a way to tell the Plist file to use the default osx settings for terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Use `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` to set the terminal settings to the default.

> There is a special environment file which loginwindow searches for each time a user logs in. The environment file is: ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist (be careful it's case sensitive). Where '~' is the home directory of the user we are interested in. You will have to create the .MacOSX directory yourself using terminal (by typing mkdir .MacOSX). You will also have to create the environment file yourself. The environment file is actually in XML/plist format (make sure to add the .plist extension to the end of the filename or this won't work).

Use the following key to set the terminal to use a shell which has default settings, such as `tcsh`:

```
  <key>SHELL</key>
  <string>/bin/tcsh</string>
```

Use `plutil` to convert the `environment.plist` file to binary format.

```
plutil -convert binary1 environment.plist
```

**References**

- [Environment Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html)
- [plutil man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/plutil.1.html)
- [Shell Script Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/shell_scripts/shell_scripts.html)